# explanation of uploading multiple apk's to android market for one app

Tags: java, android, apk

I have uploaded my app to the android market for sdk level 10, I would like to now upload more sdks to support the different version levels such as 2.1,2.2 etc, I have seen that this can be done however I find the documentation extremely confusing and cant find a straight forward tutorial anywhere for doing this, can anyone explain to me the steps I need to take to add another apk for another version? thanks In advance.

Comment: stranger thing is a friend was able to download the app on version 3.0 even tho I never specified it for that api level? now Im really confused?

Comment: What's the `minSdkVerion` that you had/have used in your manifest?

Comment: I found out by accident that once you target a minimum sdk all the ones after can be used by the app, for some reason I just assumed this process would be more complicated lol, thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation of [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html)   neatly.they have given if you select Level then for which devices it will support.its totally depend upon Level n SDK you used.i hope it will work for you.